# How to create two different environments using terraform at the same time

Tags: terraform

Below is the problem I'm trying to solve -

We have a Web application called 'deployment console' which we will use to manage our environments on AWS.

The deployment console will receive requests to create/maintain either staging/prod environments using terraform.

The console can/will receive requests in parallel.

So my question is how can run terraform in parallel to create/maintain environments based on the requests, without screwing up the state files of the respective environments

My terraform folder structure is as follows

- terraform

  - create_env.tf
  - variables.tf
  - staging.tfvars
  - prod.tfvars
  - staging_backend_cnf.tfvars
  - prod_backend_cnf.tfvars
  - ec2module

    - create_ec2.tf
    - varialbes.tf
    - output.tf
  - elbmodule

    - create_ec2.tf
    - varialbes.tf
    - output.tf
  - ec2secmodule

    - create_ec2.tf
    - varialbes.tf
    - output.tf
  - elbsecmodule

    - create_ec2.tf
    - varialbes.tf
    - output.tf

Comment: I'd say your webapp should manage prevention of concurrent runs and possibly a queue of terraform requests.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid risking state file corruption through parallel runs then you should use [state file locking](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/locking.html).

Because you seem to be using AWS you should probably be already storing your [state in S3](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html) and from there it's just a case of adding a DynamoDB lock table:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "mybucket"
    key            = "path/to/my/key"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    dynamodb_table = "mylocktable
  }
}
```